# How to get the distance from a top of an arm to a surface?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, robotics

I am studying computer science and I am working on a project for my next semester. I am stuck with a problem and I am not that good in math. Imagine I have an "arm" shape line where it has 5 nodes `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` and `E`. 4 of these nodes have an angle `b`, `c`, `d`, `e` where `A`, the 5th node, is the end of this arm.

How can I calculate `x` for this graph:

[image]

And how could I prevent this or solve this case where `x` did not change:

[image]

So generally, What is the math behind calculating the distance `x` of my end node `A` whatever the shape of my arm and however it moves?

Comment: Technically you will want to get the coordinates of $A$, then project it orthogonally to the surface somehow. To arrive at $A$, knowing the angles $b,c,d,e$ is not enough, we need to know the distances as well. How is the surface given?

Comment: @Berci Right and let's assume that distances are fixed, if you mean for the arm parts `ED`, `DC`, `CB` and `BA` and assume they are `L1`, `L2`, `L3`, `L4` respectively. Do we still need the distance from the `Surface oint` to node `E`?

Comment: Well, it depends what we know about the surface. In this generality I doubt you would find a simple formula for the problem.

Comment: The shape of the surface most definitely affects the distance from $A$ to it.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri sure. And the main goal is to analyze the shape of the surface. Here I am assuming first that it is a flat surface

Comment: It would be good to specify what kind of surface it is. Are we to suppose it is a rectangle? How far from a corner is point $E$? There are far too many variables unspecified right now. As is, the problem is underdetermined.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri What are the needed variables? What are the information that I am missing? And why at this point the matter of the surface still matters?

Comment: I meant kind as in shape. The location of point $E$ is also needed.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri so my question is: if location of E is given, so the `surface point` location is known, what would be the equation to find x?

Comment: AS starter - assume E coordinates. Using angel b and distance DE, find coordinates of D. From D find C and than follow to B and finally get A coordinates. Than you need the surface information (line definition) to get distance from it.